# Python CGI Error 500: Premature end of script headers

Tags: python, cgi

I have this fairly complex python script im trying to run which imports other self-written modules and things like sqlite. When I go to run the script, I get a 500: internal server error and the log says: Premature end of script headers.

I know this means that I probably don't have my header correctly placed/typed but I believe I do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable(logdir=..., format="text")

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
```

Looks right, right?

I continue with the script and print the results at the end. All the other modules don't have the header or the hashbang, but I think that's fine.

What could the problem be?

Comment: What happens if you run your script from command line: `python my_script.cgi`

Comment: @ms4py when i run the script with the ide i use, i get the wanted output.

Comment: Which web server are you using? Anything useful in the log?

Comment: Has the script executable permissions? `chmod +x my_script.cgi`

Comment: the site is being hosted by networksolutions and the only thing in the log is the 'premature end of script headers error'. And yes, all the scripts have a '755' status.

Comment: If you are developing under Windows, make sure that the file is saved with Unix line endings `\n`. Does a simple CGI script work or does every CGI script fail?

Comment: A colleague and I are exchanging scripts. There are developing on a Windows machine and I am on a Mac. A simple script that we both wrote does work.

Comment: Have you tried converting the line endings?

Comment: Can you try `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()` (without arguments), any helpful output now?

Comment: The cgitb.enable() doesn't appear to be doing anything, with or without arguments.

And print Content-type: text/html + print and print Content-type: text/html\n both produce the same error.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

yes. that's the thing. a simple does script works.

Comment: As already said [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901662/python-cgi-error-500-premature-end-of-script-headers#comment14213937_10901662) the line endings of your script must be the unix style `\n` instead of the Windows endings `\r\n`. The most editors are capable of letting you choose the endings.

Comment: Depends on your editor. Just use google for help, this is a very easy task!

Comment: My editor is in unix! http://i.imgur.com/plpNI.png

Comment: Well, in this case the error is probably somewhere in your code. Try to find the issue by adding portions of your code to the simple script working until you find the part of the code causing this error.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem.  This solved it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

.
.
.

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print
```