# Error 500 - Premature end of script headers

Tags: python, apache, web, cgi, mamp

I know this is a fairly common question but I've left no digital stone unturned and still can't find an answer that works for me.

I am running MAMP and Pythons 2.x **and** 3.x on a Mac running macOS Sierra. I am trying to learn Python CGI scripting and I am going through [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/webservers.html).

So far, I am at the point where I test CGI ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/webservers.html#simple-script-for-testing-cgi)). I've uploaded my file to the server with the name `index.cgi`, in `/Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/index.cgi`. However, when navigating to http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.cgi I get 500 - Internal Server Error. This occurs regardless of whether I save as a `.cgi` or `.py`.

**Here's what I've tried:**

- [Consulting the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)
- [Checking file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17626018/7450368)
- [Adjusting the `Content-Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999762/7450368)
- [Ensuring my file is in UNIX format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33136435/7450368)
- Checking the Apache error log (`Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log`)

  Note: I have also tried clearing them and then reloading to isolate the individual error - it doesn't help. All I get is `[`**`TIMESTAMP`**`] [error] [client ::1] Premature end of script headers: index.py`

**Here's the code in `index.py`/`index.cgi`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print()

print("Hello World!")
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [ScriptLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html#scriptlog) directive to get a more detailed error message?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this and so I haven't checked. I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `print("")` instead of `print()`.